# Using JSON Merge Patch, how do I reference members of sub-collection?

Tags: json, merge, json-patch

Using the [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) specification, is there a way to identify members of a sub-collection in the target - for modification or deletion?

With the twist, that `key` may be flagged as `readOnly`!

For example, given the following original JSON document:

```json
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": [
    {
      "key": "d",
      "prop1": "e",
      "prop2": "f"
    },
    {
      "key": "g",
      "prop": "h"
    }
  ]
}
```

My gut (often wrong) tells me to send the following request:

```
PATCH /target HTTP/1.1
```

```json
  "c": [
    {
      "key": "d",
      "prop1": "z"
    },
  ]
```

To get the result:

```json
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": [
    {
      "key": "d",
      "prop1": "z",
      "prop2": "f"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does this, so far, make sense according to the spec?

But, what if `key` is flagged as `readOnly` in an OpenAPI schema? In that case we shouldn't technically be allowed to pass the `key` (a UUID) on the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is not how it works. I have tested your scenario using [json-merge patch](https://github.com/pierreinglebert/json-merge-patch), an implementation of the JSON Merge Patch RFC 7396,

```
var jsonmergepatch = require('json-merge-patch');    
var source = {
  "a": "b",
  "c": [
    {
      "key": "d",
      "prop1": "e",
      "prop2": "f"
    },
    {
      "key": "g",
      "prop": "h"
    }
  ]
};    
var patch = {
  "c": [
    {
      "key": "d",
      "prop1": "z"
    },
  ]
};
var target = jsonmergepatch.apply(source, patch);
console.log(JSON.stringify(target));
```

and this outputs:

> ```
> {
>     "a": "b",
>     "c": [{
>             "key": "d",
>             "prop1": "z"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

My explanation is, the patch value specified for `c` is not an object but an array, and therefore the existing value is replaced entirely. When looking at [RFC 7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) (which obsoletes RFC 7386) we find the application of a merge patch in pseudo-code:

```
define MergePatch(Target, Patch):
 if Patch is an Object:
   if Target is not an Object:
     Target = {} # Ignore the contents and set it to an empty Object
   for each Name/Value pair in Patch:
     if Value is null:
       if Name exists in Target:
         remove the Name/Value pair from Target
     else:
       Target[Name] = MergePatch(Target[Name], Value)
   return Target
 else:
   return Patch
```

My conclusion here is, an array has no name-value pair, and therefore does not enter the recursive processing but is simply returned, which means gets replaced by the patch value in your case.

Regarding the `readOnly` flag, I strongly believe the merge patch operation is not schema-aware. The RFC does not mention anything in this respect.